# static files and django templates

Tags: python, css, django, dom, django-templates

I want to put all my `link` tags in `<head>`.

However, I don't know how to render all the `link` tags in the `head` of my DOM when I include shared templates via the built in `include` tag.  So my `link` tags are rendered wherever I happen to include my shared templates.  I've added code below to better illustrate my problem.

Layout:

```
<html>
<head>
    {% block references %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Extending the layout with a template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
...
{% include "mySharedTemplate.html" %}
...
```

Shared template.  Note, this template is shared among a few but not all of my templates:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
...
```

Is there a way to put all my `link` tags in the `head` of my DOM while using shared templates?  Is there a completely different or better way to do this?  I'm a week into my first django project, so even suggestions of basic features may help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky way to do this.  I'm not super pleased with it.  I found that I can use simple `if` blocks to toggle which sections of my template I want to render with the `include` tag.  This allows me to include my references and content separately.  (Note, I could solve this problem by separating my references and content into separate files.  But that seems more tedious than this solution.)

I like this solution better than the current answers because it allows my shared template to be isolated from other templates.  Keeping this modular design is important when working with functionality that you can mix and match (which is what I'd like to do with my shared templates).

Template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
    {% include "mySharedTemplate.html" with references="True" %}
{% endblock %}
...
{% include "mySharedTemplate.html" with content="True" %}
...
```

Shared Template:

```
{% if references %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endif %}
{% if content %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

To illustrate why I think my modular design is important:

Imagine I have a many shared templates and many regular templates that each use the shared templates in different ways.  My modular method makes it easy for regular templates to work with shared templates in flexible ways that best suit them.

Template 2:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
    {% include "mySharedTemplate.html" with references="True" %}
    {% include "mySharedTemplate2.html" with references="True" %}
{% endblock %}
...
{% include "mySharedTemplate.html" with content="True" %}
{% include "mySharedTemplate2.html" with content="True" %}
...
```

Template 3:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
    {% include "mySharedTemplate2.html" with references="True" %}
    {% include "mySharedTemplate3.html" with references="True" %}
    {% include "mySharedTemplate4.html" with references="True" %}
{% endblock %}
...
{% include "mySharedTemplate4.html" with content="True" %}
{% include "mySharedTemplate3.html" with content="True" %}
{% include "mySharedTemplate2.html" with content="True" %}
...
```

Notice that Template 2 and Template 3 can use the the shared templates in ways that suit them without much boiler plate code.

Comment: How about shared template into two parts: one for reference, the other for cotnent.

Comment: @falsetru I think I tried to do that by putting them in separate `if` blocks.  Is there a better way I can do this?  Can I include specific `blocks` with the `include` tag?

Comment: I explain why I didn't do that in my answer.  _Note, I could solve this problem by separating my references and content into separate files. But that seems more tedious than this solution._

Comment: I don't know way to include specific blocks except your method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are lookig for `{{block.super}}`

for example Layout.html:

```
<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">

{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and in Template.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    {{block.super}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

if you do not want to use the `mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css` for all your pages you only do not use `{{block.super}}` like Template2.html:

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block references %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'd rather not put `mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css` in my layout because not all templates use the shared template markup.

Comment: I'd rather just include `mySharedTemplateStylesheet.css` in template.html rather than use `block.super`.  They both basically do the same thing.  `block.super` just obfuscates the code and makes the `references` block in layout.html include code that it doesn't need to.

Comment: I've added an answer myself. Please explain why you think your solution or another solution is better if you think this to be the case. I'd be happy to engage! I hate providing my own answers :).

Answer (score 1):

layout.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    {% block references %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

layout-with-shared-css.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

template without shared template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

template with shared template:

```
{% extends "layout-shared-css.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block references %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myStylesheet.css" %}" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'd rather not do this because not all my pages use the "shared template".

Comment: @steaks, How many times "shared template" is used? If it frequently used, try Victor Castillo Torres's answer.

Comment: @steaks, I updated code for case when "shared template" is rarely used.

Comment: Your answer puts the link _and_ markup of the shared template in the references block.  Doesn't that makes the shared template render incorrectly because the markup will be rendered in the `head` of the DOM?

Comment: No there is more.  That's what I meant by the ellipsis.  See the `...`

Comment: Unfortunately I also don't like this. You've basically created a way to include shared templates through inheritance. Inheritance tends to not scale well functionality that can be mixed and matched between objects (which to my understanding is the point of shared templates).  Imagine I have 10 shared templates in the future.  I'd need to have dozens of layouts that combine each of these shared templates in different ways so that my page templates could use the shared templates in flexible and different ways.

Comment: I've added an answer myself.  Please explain why you think your solution or another solution is better if you think this to be the case.  I'd be happy to engage!  I hate providing my own answers :).

Answer (score 0):

Use `verbatim` tag to stop template engine to interpret your tags to be his tags.

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

[Django and Chartjs template conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523909/django-and-chartjs-template-conflict)