# Django and Chartjs template conflict

Tags: django, django-templates, chart.js

I'm trying to set the `tooltipTemplate` property of a line chart to `<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>`, but I'm using Django on the backend. So, if I try to use the literal value of `tooltipTemplate`, Django will interpret the `{%` and `%}` as part of its template language. How can I avoid this?

`tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [verbatim tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim).

```
{% verbatim %}
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>"
{% endverbatim %}
```

There is also a [templatetag tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) which you can use to output special template tag characters, but that would be quite verbose.

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){% templatetag openblock %}><%=label%>: <%{% templatetag closeblock %}><%= value %>"
```